# BCP: Error Running BCP in SQL Server but not in cmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, delimiter, bcp

I am able to run `bcp` commands on the command line, but unfortunately when trying in SQL Server, I see the following error:

> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file

This is the code I use in SQL Server:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT ''col1'', ''col2'' union all select col1, col2FROM [kat].[dbo].[Table_Data] WITH (NOLOCK)" queryout ''C:\Users\kata\exportFiles\FirstTestOutput.csv''  -t; -c -T'
```

Could it be an error with the quotes "**'**"?

Many thanks in advance,

Kat

Comment: It means that the SQL Server service account can't get to path `C:\Users\kata\exportFiles\FirstTestOutput.csv`. This looks like a local user specific path. Make it something more generic like `C:\temp\output.csv`

Comment: Thanks, but after changing I see the same problem

Comment: Ok I changed the command and the folder and now it is working, but why is working with some locations and not others?

Answer (score 1):

'xp_cmdshell' has to run as "someone". It doesn't run as you. It runs as the "SQL Server service account". That is an account set up in a the "services applet". By default it's an account that won't have rights to your personal folders. So you either change this service account to have more rights or you only use folders that it has rights to.